# Highlight meetings that have an attendee from outside of my organisation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I want to apply a conditional formatting rule to my Outlook calendar to highlight meetings that have a required attendee from outside of my organisation.

Clients still come to our office for meetings, so can't do it via location or room and a NOT rule.  Perhaps some kind of NOT rule and a wildcard against our domain email address?